# How can I get rid of "Caller Name ID" from notification panel?

Tags: notifications, notification-bar, caller-id

"Caller Name ID" appears on the notification panel constantly even though I clear all the notifications.

How can get rid of this?

(I'm not asking how to uninstall this app.)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tap and hold on the notification. Assuming Samsung hasn't altered the Lollipop interface too much, you should see a small Info icon in the corner after it switches. Tap that, and you'll be presented with three options for notifications for that app, one of which is to block them entirely.

Alternatively you can access notification settings from the phone's main settings app (again, as I'm on stock, I can't speak to Samsung's exact method for accessing this) and find the app in that list and alter its settings. You can also use this to undo something you blocked in error.